# Flutter ListView working in Column but not in Row

Tags: flutter

I am trying to populate some data in a row. But whenever I run the following code it gives error.

**Code**

```
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: Row(
         mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
         children: [
           ListView.builder(
             shrinkWrap: true,
             itemCount: rideInfo[0]['matched'][0]['companionInfo'].length,
             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               return Container(
                 color: Colors.red,
                 height: 40,
                 width: 40,
                 child: Text("Test"),
               );
              },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

**Error**

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1890 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedWidth': is not true.
package:flutter/…/rendering/viewport.dart:1890
2

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
```

However if I change *Row to Column*, it seems to be working fine. How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not two infinite scroll widget in the same widget tree. You are using `SingleChildScrollView` and `Listview` both in the same widget tree. You have change this like:

```
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: Row(
         mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
         children: [
              SizedBox(
                  height: 50,   
                  child:ListView.builder(
                       scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal,
                       shrinkWrap: true,
                       itemCount: rideInfo[0]['matched'][0]['companionInfo'].length,
             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               return Container(
                 color: Colors.red,
                 height: 40,
                 width: 40,
                 child: Text("Test"),
               );
              },
          ),
              )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```